# Syntax error for else and elif

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to separate a file of 1500 lines into metadata and data.

Here is what I have:

```
headerLines = []
dataLines = []
for line in lineList:
    if (len(line) > 0 and (line[0] == # )) :
        headerLines.append(line)     
    elif (len(line) > 0 and (line[0] == U ):
        dataLines.append(line)
print("we have {} lines of metadata".format(len(headerLines)))
print("we have {} lines of data".format(len(dataLines)))       

#here we want to seperate the lines in the file into headerLines and dataLines
```

Comment: Could you explain what error you're getting?

Comment: The professor gave the first 3 lines and the last two, we only had to fill in the " if " statements, I also added the missing parentheses on the  '' elif " and it did not change any thing, it just keep saying syntax error invalid syntax with a little carrot pointing at the elif.

Comment: Seems like it's the `#` which is special character to comment a line in python. Everything after the hash sign is considered removed.

Comment: the # does make the rest of the line italicized, thats how he told us to seperate the lines,I tried putting it in quotes but then it gives an int str error

Comment: you are awesome,  I tried it again and it told me U was undefined so I added quotes around the u also and ran it and it now says 24 lines of metadata and 1400 line of data,,THANKS, The line counter on this section is at 752, lets just say I have been fighting this for several days, thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in your parsing. Change the line:

```
    if (len(line) > 0 and (line[0] == # )) :
```

to

```
    if (len(line) > 0 and (line[0] == '#' )):
```

What is happening is that the hash (#) is seen as a comment, and as such everything after it is ignored (that's why it's grey). What I did to fix it is I changed it into a string, which inevitably fixes another problem with the script anyways. If line[0] is a piece of text with the value #, then it will be printed as a string, '#', so if we check for that instead, it will work just fine.

You are doing an amazing job for someone with dyslexia, and good on you for trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

This line need ')' at the end.
Like this:
    elif (len(line) > 0 and (line[0] == U )):

Another problem:
    if (len(line) > 0 and (line[0] == '#' )):

'#' is an operator.Just like +/-， you cannot compare 'aaa' to +/-.